# Karatsuba multiplication in swift

Tags: swift, algorithm, math, largenumber, karatsuba

I was trying to implement Karatsuba multiplication in swift. I wrote the below code and it is working fine for some smaller numbers but as the number gets bigger this code fails to give the correct answer. I have debugged in every possible way I can but could not find the bug. Algorithm wise I think I did correctly write the code. And the code is working fine for smaller numbers. But the final answer is wrong for bigger numbers. If anyone out there can crack down the mistake I'm making, pls do help me

```
func findMultiplication(x: String, y: String) -> String {
    
    if isZero(str: x) || isZero(str: y) {
        return "0"
    }
    var x = removeLeadingZeros(number: x)
    var y = removeLeadingZeros(number: y)
    if x.count < 2 || y.count < 2 {
        let result = Int(x)!*Int(y)!
        return String(result)
    }
    
    var middleIndexX: String.Index
    var middleIndexY: String.Index
    var middleIndex: Int
    
    if x.count >= y.count {
        y = addLeftPaddingZeros(numberOfZeros: x.count-y.count, for: y)
        middleIndex = x.count / 2
        if x.count % 2 != 0 {
            middleIndex += 1
        }
    } else {
        x = addLeftPaddingZeros(numberOfZeros: y.count-x.count, for: x)
        middleIndex = y.count / 2
        if y.count % 2 != 0 {
            middleIndex += 1
        }
    }
    middleIndexX = x.index(x.startIndex, offsetBy: middleIndex)
    middleIndexY = y.index(y.startIndex, offsetBy: middleIndex)
    
    let a = String(x[x.startIndex..<middleIndexX])
    let b = String(x[middleIndexX..<x.endIndex])
    let c = String(y[y.startIndex..<middleIndexY])
    let d = String(y[middleIndexY..<y.endIndex])
    
    let ac = findMultiplication(x: a, y: c)
    let bd = findMultiplication(x: b, y: d)
    let aPb = Int(a)! + Int(b)!
    let cPd = Int(c)! + Int(d)!
    let gauss = findMultiplication(x: String(aPb), y: String(cPd))
    let thirdItem = String(Int(gauss)! - Int(ac)! - Int(bd)!)
    
    var returnSum = 0
    returnSum += Int(addLeftPaddingZeros(numberOfZeros: x.count, for: ac, isLeft: false)) ?? 0
    returnSum += Int(addLeftPaddingZeros(numberOfZeros: middleIndex, for: thirdItem, isLeft: false)) ?? 0
    returnSum += Int(bd) ?? 0
    return String(returnSum)
}

print(findMultiplication(x: "123400", y: "123711"))
```

```
func removeLeadingZeros(number: String) -> String {
    var number = number
    while number.first == "0" {
        number.removeFirst()
    }
    if number == "" {
        return "0"
    }
    return number
}
```

```
//The function name is given like this only. BUt his will help to add padding zero in left and right also

func addLeftPaddingZeros(numberOfZeros: Int, for str: String, isLeft: Bool = true) -> String {
    var padding = ""
    for _ in 0 ..< numberOfZeros {
        padding += "0"
    }
    if isLeft {
        return padding+str
    } else {
        return str + padding
    }
    
}
```

```
func isZero(str: String) -> Bool {
    for char in str {
        if char != "0" {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: It seems to fail pretty quickly, 3 digit string multiplied by a 2 digit string, and the error seems to always be that an extra 0 is added to the answer. Maybe this can help you with the troubleshooting

Comment: @JoakimDanielson But I'm adding that zeros on the left side. And also considering the leading zeros in further multiplications

Comment: The scaling/padding for "the middle parts" is `middleIndex`. Now what *should* it be for the high part, `ac`? (You are welcome to answer your own question.)

Comment: @greybeard middleIndex is just for splitting the current number string in half. The ```ac```  we are getting from the first number string's first half, and is obtained using middleIndex.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson That padding of zeros was to just make the numbers equal in length. But those will be cleared during the addition steps

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I am trying to figure out what's wrong there. The padding of zeros are actually needed, right?. otherwise, the splitting will make problems

Comment: Look, the only way I could tell exactly what is wrong with your code is by running it in the debugger or adding a bunch of print statements and I see no reason why I should do that when you can do it instead. Like I said it only takes two relatively small numbers to reproduce this so it shouldn’t be that hard. Try for instance "123" & "12"

Comment: You are using `x.count` for scaling/padding `ac`. What *should* be used when both `a` and `c` where both obtained using a scale/padding of `middleIndex`? (Or were they, in case of odd "count"? Are you taking `middleIndex` *most* or *least* significant digits? It gets more confusing if you don't use *least*, but I can only recommend to quit thinking "digits", anyway.)

Answer (score -1):

There's an implementation here:
https://victorqi.gitbooks.io/swift-algorithm/content/karatsuba-multiplication.html
Their code reads:

```swift
// Karatsuba Multiplication
func karatsuba(_ num1: Int, by num2: Int) -> Int {
  let num1Array = String(num1).characters
  let num2Array = String(num2).characters

  guard num1Array.count > 1 && num2Array.count > 1 else {
    return num1*num2
  }

  let n = max(num1Array.count, num2Array.count)
  let nBy2 = n / 2

  let a = num1 / 10^^nBy2
  let b = num1 % 10^^nBy2
  let c = num2 / 10^^nBy2
  let d = num2 % 10^^nBy2

  let ac = karatsuba(a, by: c)
  let bd = karatsuba(b, by: d)
  let adPlusbc = karatsuba(a+b, by: c+d) - ac - bd

  let product = ac * 10^^(2 * nBy2) + adPlusbc * 10^^nBy2 + bd

  return product
}
```

Comment: That's not very helpful. The OP asks that the OP's own code be examined. Throwing a bunch of completely alternative code at the wall, with the no explanation, is not really an answer.